# How to find vulnerabilities and secure cPanel & WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, security, cpanel

I have five websites in my shared hosting. In last few days, I have got attacked several times. After getting malicious files in my directory, I have been removed those files and upload a fresh back-up file of my websites. But after two or three days again got attacked. At this moment I couldn't find the vulnerabilities. Is there any way to find out the weak point from where websites getting infected?

Comment: Consulting with your hosting would be the best course of action, as they can see trafic to your site and pin point problamatic IPs and urls.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: If it is shared or own server better to do reset your cPanel account change cPanel username and password set password length minimum 25 characters.

Method 2 : if it is wordpress  platform, install wordfense antivirus and find vulnarability on your web directory in plugin category.